# For the PubNub iOS SDK 4.0, maximum number of channels a client can subscribe to, without turning on stream controller?

Tags: ios, pubnub

For the PubNub iOS SDK 4.0, maximum number of channels a client can subscribe to, without turning on Stream Controller? I couldn't seem to find a definite answer. On PubNub's own documentation and knowledge base, the number 10, 20, 50 and 100 were mentioned. It is unclear if these numbers require Stream Controller to be turned on.

I understand that by using Channel Groups under the Stream Controller add-on, maximum is 20,000 (2,000 * 10 = 20,000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PubNub iOS SDK 4.0 Multiplex vs Channel Group vs Wildcard

For the PubNub iOS SDK 4.0 in terms of multiplexing the SDK supports up to about **50 channels practically**.  You can increase this number further but device performance will be impacted.  It is better to utilize the **Channel Group** feature of the core [PubNub Stream Controller](http://www.pubnub.com/products/stream-controller/) product.  Stream Controller includes the following channel subscription enhancements.

### Wildcard Subscribe

***Maximum Addressable Channels: ( Unlimited )***

PubNub Also supports [Wildcard Subscriptions using a Hierarchical dot notation](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference#subscribe_example_wildcard).  Today in PubNub you can subscribe to channel **`"a.b.*"`** and receive messages at any channel below `a.b`.  You could publish to channel **`"a.b.c"`** and receive the message in your wildcard subscribe.  Note that the maximum depth supported of the hierarchy is currently a depth of **three**.  For example **`"a.b.*"`** is good but **`"a.b.c.*"`** is not supported.

### Channel Groups

***Maximum Addressable Channels: ( 2,000 ✕ 10 ＝ 20,000 )***

Dynamically control the device's data stream feed with PubNub Channel Groups.  You can remotely control which streams the device is subscribed to and dynamically **add** and **remove** channels from the list of channels.  You can multiplex subscribe up to 10 channel groups and each channel group can contain up to 2,000 channels.

### Multiplexing

***Maximum Addressable Channels: ( ~100 )***

You can multiplex your connection by subscribing to a combination of **Wildcard Channels**, **Channel Groups**, **Presence Event Stream Channels** and more.  It is recommended to keep your multiplexed channels below 50 for best device performance.

Comment: Thank you! So for a single client instance and WITHOUT turning on the Stream Controller add-on, my app can connect up to 50 channels? Sorry but I would like to confirm the part regarding "WITHOUT turning on Stream Controller add-on".

Comment: Yes I am confirming your `50 channel limit` recommendation.  However multiplexing is a feature under **`Stream Controller`** product and is reserved to be tied to this product as a restrictive service feature setting.